# Pushing Data to Matching Row in Index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Sheets and I'm trying to implement a script that will push data from **'stage 1 analysis'F:H** back to **'master list'F:H**.

I don't seem to be able to get my head around the code for matching the name values in the dropdown to the correct row in master list.

I managed to get a button working to push the analysis data to a new helper sheet which I could then filter back to the master list but this hardly seems optimal.

[Here's my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YtqQjVR6m7RETuTVV3CUmPrMMUuLUF5QAhlyEOgHcIw/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Here's my current function

```
function myFunction(){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//this is the active spreadsheet

var sh=ss.getSheetByName("stage 1 analysis");//this gets the stage 1 analysis sheet

var rg=sh.getRange(2,6,sh.getLastRow()-1,3);//this gets the range of available data on staget 1 analysis sheet

var vA=rg.getValues();//this gets the values from stage 1 analysis into a 2 dimensional array.  Note for future use even a 1 column or 1row is a 2d array.

var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("master list");//this gets the master list sheet

tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,6,vA.length,3).setValues(vA);//this defines the range which is the next available row with no data in it that fits the 2 dimensional array from stage 1 analysis sheet.
}
```

The getRange function allows me to add the calculated data back into the Master List into an empty row. What I'm looking to achieve is having that data go into the rows that correspond with the names.

As usual any help would be appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code to your question and let us know what part you are stuck on.

Comment: If this is a lot more complex than I've been lead to believe please feel free to direct me to a relevant resource to continue my learning.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. Do you just want to copy the two calculation values (columns F and H) for each row in `stage 1 analysis` to the corresponding row in `master list`?

Comment: Exactly, excuse my ignorance.
So copy 'stage 1 analysis'F2:H2 back to 'master list'F:H in the row that matches the currently selected 'stage 1 analysis'A2

Comment: Hi S1c0j1, any thoughts on how the data should be distributed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the distribution of data. @Cooper might be able to help?

Comment: Just what I mentioned before about the data being populated in the corresponding row. No worries, will keep reading.

Comment: At the moment the data that's returned in the Master List sheet is added to the next available row where as I need to it be in the row that corresponds to the Name.

Comment: Why don't you just use a lookup formula? Or do you expect the values on the analysis sheet to change and you want the master sheet to be static?

Comment: Yes so the Analysis sheet will be constantly changed and many more variables added for the intended purpose. The purpose of the Master List is to save the the analysis data for each entry as a sort of index. Sorry bit long winded, does that make sense?

Comment: Makes sense. Will the function be triggered by a user or at specified times?

Comment: Triggered by a user via a button I will add on the Analysis page.
So step by step, a new entry is added to master list via a form, that new entry is automatically assigned to stage 1, only stage 1 entries are visible in the analysis page via the dropdown menu, I need to then save all of the calculated data back into master list into the corresponding row.

Comment: I'm back to work tomorrow after being on holiday, I'm afraid I cannot assist further. I don't wish to deprive @Cooper of the reputation, but if this question hasn't actually been answered, you may wish to unaccept his or her answer as this will show that you are still waiting for one.

Comment: No worries mate, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I read your comments and updated the function.  It wasn't very clear to me what you wanted before so I just gave you something to help you get started.  But I think the current answer is closer to what you want.  We could actually perform the stage 1 analysis with the script if you would prefer and then not even require the stage 1 analysis sheet but I just did what you request and that was to copy the data from one sheet to another if the column1 names are the same.

Comment: I also went ahead and added the code to install a button to call the function from a sidebar on the spreadsheet.  Just put that in a menu and you can bring the sidebar up anytime you wish.  I use side bars a lot when I'm running commands a lot because it just requires one click and you don't have to mess around with drop down menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function goes through the master list looking for lines in the 'stage 1 analysis sheet that have the same name.  If found it copies the data from stage 1 analysis in columns F and H to the master list.

```
function stageOneAnalysisToMasterList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("stage 1 analysis");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("master list");
  var trg=tsh.getDataRange();
  var tvA=trg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<tvA.length;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<vA.length;j++){
      if(tvA[i][0]==vA[j][0]){
        tvA[i][5]=vA[j][5];
        tvA[i][7]=vA[j][7];
      }
    }
  }
  trg.setValues(tvA);
}
```

I added the code to put your button in a sidebar on the spreadsheet.

```
function stage1AnalysisSideBar(){
  var html='<input type="button" value="Copy Stage 1 to MasterList" onClick="google.script.run.stageOneAnalysisToMasterList()" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

**References**

- [SpreadSheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

I hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, I'm finding that this is only returning the first calculation 3 times.

Comment: All good, changed the setValue in the last line to setValues and it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Yes. That was a mistake it’s supposed to be setValues().

Comment: Thanks for your help Cooper, seem to be getting an error for outputting to cell 5 on line 12.
TypeError: Cannot read property "5" from undefined. (line 12, file "Code")
Do I need to set a variable for the target cells?

Comment: Do you have headings in your master list in columns f and h?

Comment: I do, the first row of both sheets contains a header.

Comment: The spreadsheet is attached in the original post if you fancy taking a look.

Comment: I have but I wasn't sure if you were using the same spreadsheet.  It tested in on my end and it appears to work okay.  I did have an error in the sidebar code so you might want to get the change that I made to that.  Added a `';` to the html.

Comment: If your going to use the sidebar just go ahead and replace that code because I made another small change to it and no it's working too.

Comment: Damn that's really strange, any chance you could take a look at the live version for me? I've made the sheet and scripts editable.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YtqQjVR6m7RETuTVV3CUmPrMMUuLUF5QAhlyEOgHcIw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to clarify the reason for having a separate sheet to perform the calculations is that in practice the sheet will have a number adjustable fields and will allow the user to compare many calculations with multiple versions before submitting the data back to the master list.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. It's running now. Just a matter of turning some i's into j's

Comment: The reality is that learning how to debug code is purely a matter of experience.  The more you do the better you get.